# Add worksheets to array by VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I practice on VBA for one month and I have some problem.I want to create array from data in worksheet by this loop but it doesn't work. I have 6 worksheets but it can get only one worksheet into array. I think problem in this loop is DataArray but I can't solve it.

```
Sub LoopByArray()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim DataArray() As Variant
    Dim Sheetnum As String
    Dim SheetNames()
    Dim i As Long

    SheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    ReDim SheetNames(1 To SheetCount)

    For i = 1 To SheetCount
        SheetNames(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        Debug.Print SheetNames(i) 
        Sheetnum = i
        Set ws = worksheets(SheetNames(i))
        LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames(i)).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Debug.Print LastRow

        LastCol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames(i)).Cells(1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames(i)).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Debug.Print LastCol

        ColLetter = GetColumnLetter(LastCol)
        DataArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames(i)).Range("A1" & ":" & ColLetter & LastRow).Value

    Next i

End Sub

Function GetColumnLetter(colNum As Long) As String
    
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, colNum).Address(True, False), "$")
    GetColumnLetter = vArr(0)

End Function
```

Comment: You want one array containing data form all sheets?  How should it be arranged if (eg) different sheets have different # of rows or cols ?

Comment: I think I should create more arrays to get another worksheets but I don't know how to add them to this loop.

Comment: Is it possible to create loop or another functions to define array variables based on number of sheets in VBA?

Comment: What are you going to do with the arrays ?

Comment: I try to gat data and use vlookup in array because I think it will be faster than in worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of possibilities to work with

```
Public Sub Shts2Arrays()
  Dim ShtAR1() As Variant, ShtAR2() As Variant, ShtAR3() As Variant
  Dim i As Integer, J As Integer
  
  ShtAR1 = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
  ShtAR2 = Sheets(2).UsedRange.Value
  ShtAR3 = Sheets(3).UsedRange.Value
  
  For i = LBound(ShtAR1) To UBound(ShtAR1)
     For J = 1 To Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Debug.Print i, J, ShtAR1(i, J)
     Next J
  Next i
  
  For i = LBound(ShtAR2) To UBound(ShtAR2)
     For J = 1 To Sheets(2).UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Debug.Print i, J, ShtAR2(i, J)
     Next J
  Next i
  
  For i = LBound(ShtAR3) To UBound(ShtAR3)
     For J = 1 To Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Debug.Print i, J, ShtAR3(i, J)
     Next J
  Next i
  
End Sub
```

In the following the arrays are transposed using Application.Transpose otherwise the same

```
Public Sub TransposeShts2Arrays()
  Dim ShtAR1() As Variant, ShtAR2() As Variant, ShtAR3() As Variant
  Dim i As Integer, J As Integer
  
  ShtAR1 = Application.Transpose(Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value)
  ShtAR2 = Application.Transpose(Sheets(2).UsedRange.Value)
  ShtAR3 = Application.Transpose(Sheets(3).UsedRange.Value)
  
  For i = LBound(ShtAR1) To UBound(ShtAR1)
     For J = 1 To Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Debug.Print i, J, ShtAR1(i, J)
     Next J
  Next i
  
  For i = LBound(ShtAR2) To UBound(ShtAR2)
     For J = 1 To Sheets(2).UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Debug.Print i, J, ShtAR2(i, J)
     Next J
  Next i
  
  For i = LBound(ShtAR3) To UBound(ShtAR3)
     For J = 1 To Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Debug.Print i, J, ShtAR3(i, J)
     Next J
  Next i
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make dataArray() a 1D array.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FillArrays()
    
    Dim dataArray(), wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
   
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ReDim dataArray(wb.Sheets.Count)

    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        dataArray(ws.Index) = ws.UsedRange.Value
    Next
    Debug.Print dataArray(3)(1, 1) 'Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```